# return value based on a string

Tags: c#, asp.net, string, linq, return

Hi I have created a class to get values form my customer's account table, I have created a class for that. I want to inform AccountId and the Field of the table I want the result back (for example FirstName). What is the best way to achieve this? I got something like the below as my alternative but I can't make it work...

This is how I want to get the result of first name:

```
   LabelFirstName.Text = Manage.GetAccount(2, "FirstName"); // where 2 is the id I informed and FirstName is the Column I want to retrieve from the table.
```

the result would be "John" for example.

### This is what I have:

```
public class Manage
{

    public Manage()
    {
    }

    public static string GetAccount(int AccountId, string Field)
    {
        LinqSqlDataContext contextLoad = new LinqSqlDataContext();

        var q = (from p in contextLoad.MyAccounts
                 where p.AccountId == AccountId
                 select p).Single();

        string var = q.??    // ?? would be my Field string "FirstName" for example

        return var;
    }

}
```

---

Please help

Thanks

Comment: Altough there is surely some awesome answer ([Reflection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7ykdhsy(v=vs.100).aspx) for one) on how to achieve what you want I would like to ask first this: **What** are you trying to achieve here because I'm afraid I see a big antipattern here or at least some reinventing the wheel. What would you do if you needed Firstname, address street, phonenumber and e-mail? Call this function 4 times?

Comment: yes Roblll, I woudl like to fill a form in a webpage with all the details of this account, name, surname, street, etc... so I was thinking that I would have to call the function too many times... what would you recommend in this case? Is run the linq query in the page itself a better solution? Thanks.

Comment: @Gurizao Then just return q, e.g. the entire "account object" (as [demonstrated by SidAhmed](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11667656/215042)) so you can access it's properties in your view.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you return the Account object, and then retreive the property where you need it, like this :

```
public static Account GetAccount(int AccountId)
{
    LinqSqlDataContext contextLoad = new LinqSqlDataContext();

    var q = (from p in contextLoad.MyAccounts
             where p.AccountId == AccountId
             select p).Single();

    return q;
}

public void myMethod()
{
    var account = GetAccout(2);

    var accountName = account.FirstName;
    var accountNumber = account.Number;
    // ... and so on
}
```

If this is realy not helpful, you can use reflection like mentioned in other posts.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You can return the Object of the class

```
   public static Object GetAccount(int AccountId)
    {
        LinqSqlDataContext contextLoad = new LinqSqlDataContext();       
        var q = (from p in contextLoad.MyAccounts
                 where p.AccountId == AccountId
                 select p).FirstOrDefault();

        return q;
    }

var Account = GetAccount(int AccountId) as Account;
LabelFirstName.Text = Account.FirstName;
LabelLastName.Text = Account.LastName;
```

You can get all the field from the object !! So task will be achievable from one database call

Comment: Uh... how does that use the passed-in `Field` parameter so `Flav` can specify which fields value to return? How would this help when `Field` would contain 'email' for example? It would still return `FirstName` as opposed to the requested 'email`.

Comment: The clue of the question is to pass the fieldname dynamically and what you are suggesting does not solve that.

Comment: @huMptyduMpty Actually, you editted the (your) *answer*, not the question ;-) And it still doesn't answer `Flav`'s question: how to be able to specify which field/property's value to return. Regardless the fact the you could obviously just return the entire object.

Comment: @Roblll: I would like to fill a form in a webpage with all the details of this account, name, surname, street, etc... so I was thinking that I would have to call the function too many times... what would you recommend in this case? Is run the linq query in the page itself a better solution? Thanks

Comment: @Gurizao: To retrieve data by calling a method every time will definitely slow down your server as well as the page load time as well. Since you loading data related to one Account, best possible way is to load data is loading a Account object and get the data from it !!

Answer (score 0):

```
string value = (string)q.GetType().GetProperty(Field).GetValue(q, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

A DataReader might be useful in this situation:

```
    var q = from p in contextLoad.MyAccounts 
             where p.AccountId == AccountId 
             select p;


using (var command = dc.GetCommand(q)) 
{ 
    command.Connection.Open(); 
    using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader()) 
    { 
        // expecting one row
        if(reader.Read())
        { 
            return reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal(Value)); 
        } 
    } 
    return null;
}
```